# Any way to jump to the specific location in file dialog boxes?

Tags: ubuntu, dialog

Is there a way to enter the location manually? I could copy the location from the right-click menu, but can't paste it from clipboard or jump to desired location fast. Do I really need to dig through the directories each time or there is some better way? Search box just does search in current directory and don't allow me to jump anywhere else...

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and suppose it's a GTK4 thing to draw file dialogs like this:

[image: screenshot of file open dialog]

Comment: I don't have Gnome or anything GTK installed right now so this is a comment rather than an answer, but does the `/` keybind no longer work (or not work in this context)?

Comment: To my pity, this does no effect

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. (I'm refering to todays versions, sometimes principles change with new coming software versions, unfortunately)

**By pressing Ctrl+L** the breadcrumb bar changes into a path input field. FYI: this shortcut is consistent with many programs that work on a location, like Firefox, Dolphin, ...

Before it also worked to just click next to the breadcrumb, but that has already changed apparently. Hope that is not a bad omen for before mentioned version changes.